# dynamically generating unique combo box and filling them with two different sources

Tags: python, list, pyqt4, qcombobox

I want to dynamically generate Label on left & combos on the right in a grid

```
{'PHOTOSHOP': '6.5', 'NUKE': '7.0v9', 'MAYA': '2014', 'TESTING': '1.28', 'KATANA': '1.7', 'MARI': '4.0'} 
{'PHOTOSHOP': '10.5', 'NUKE': '6.3v6', 'MAYA': '2012', 'TESTING': '1.28', 'KATANA': '1.0', 'MARI': '1.0'}
```

my first problem is creating combos box in a way i can access them later outside the method based on name created at the time of for loop

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    """docstring for MainWindow"""
    def __init__(self, dataIn1, dataIn2):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self._dataIn1 =  dataIn1
        self._dataIn2 = dataIn2
        self.buildUI()

    def main(self):
        self.show()

    def buildUI(self):
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            self.gridLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox('combo')
        for index, item in enumerate(self._dataIn1.iteritems()):
            # Below line doesn't work which i want to make work
            # objective is to assign unique name so i can access-
            # them later outside this method
            #self.item[0]+"_Combo" = QtGui.QComboBox()
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel(item[0]), index, 0)
            # once uique combo is created I want to populate them from dataIn1 & dataIn2 lists
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.combo.addItems([item[-1]]), index, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Experiment')

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    smObj = MainWindow(dataIn1, dataIn2)
    smObj.main()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

secondly I want to those combo box to be filled in by each Keys value from both dataIn1 and dataIn2 sources..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically create attributes, you can use [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(self, 'combo%d' % index, combo)
```

However, it's probably much more flexible to keep the combos in a list (then you can easily iterate over them afterwards).

Your loop should end up looking something like this:

```
    data1 = {
        'PHOTOSHOP': '6.5', 'NUKE': '7.0v9', 'MAYA': '2014',
        'TESTING': '1.28', 'KATANA': '1.7', 'MARI': '4.0',
        }
    data2 = {
        'PHOTOSHOP': '10.5', 'NUKE': '6.3v6', 'MAYA': '2012',
        'TESTING': '1.28', 'KATANA': '1.0', 'MARI': '1.0',
        }
    self.combos = []
    for index, (key, value) in enumerate(data1.items()):
        label = QtGui.QLabel(key, self)
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem(value)
        combo.addItem(data2[key])
        self.combos.append(combo)
        # or setattr(self, 'combo%d' % index, combo)
        layout.addWidget(label, index, 0)
        layout.addWidget(combo, index, 1)
```

Comment: not quite what I was expecting, because the two dictionary data1 and data2 shares same keys but different values , so for that I wanted same keys as label and corresponding combo box to get populated its value from both the data1 and data2,  my apologies I should have posted the dictionaries earlier: I have updated above now.

Comment: @san. I've edited my answer to fit the new spec. But really, these were trivial alterations that you could have easily made yourself. If you expect every line of code to be written for you, you're going to very quickly run out of people willing to help you.

Comment: actually i figured out while you were updating the code, thanks anyway however I was trying to achieve through gridLayout .